# How to alignItems: flex-start inside a Text component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to `alignItems: 'flex-start';` in the following react native code without changing the surrounding element to a `<View/>`?:

```
<Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>$500.</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: '10px'}}>50</Text>
</Text>
```

The reason I don't wan't to change it into a `<View/>` is because I would like to keep the same properties a surrounding `<Text/>` gives like inheriting a parent element text color.

Comment: please add your output ?

Answer (score 1):

React native **text styles supports verticalAlign and textAlignVertical** properties for such cases, But this is **supported by android devices only** **not for iOS** as per their [text style documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props).

I guess the only options is available **for iOS that is you will need to use View and alignItems** to achieve your desired outcome.